# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS slow boot after installing Kali Linux (Triple Boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, boot-time

I had Ubuntu 18.04.3 dual boot with Windows 10 (Windows is on 2nd drive) and never had a issue with slow booting time. After installing Kali Linux on the same drive where Ubuntu is installed, Ubuntu boot time increased about 1 min, before it was 10 or 20 sec. Below is the drive info on which both OS are installed

[image: gparted screenshot]

```
Kali Linux: /dev/sda3
Kali linux-swap: /dev/sda4
Ubuntu: /dev/sda6
Ubuntu linux-swap: /dev/sda5
```

What should I do to fix the boot time?

Comment: Kali linux probably formatted the swap partition, and your Ubuntu is looking (and waiting) for the old swap UUID to appear, before eventually timeout occurs & it gives up (thus slower boot).  You need to change the UUID's for your old swap partition to match your new UUID.  My 2c guess anyway.

Comment: @guiverc slow boot issue is with ubuntu only not with other OS installed. Can you please tell me how to change UUID?

Comment: Windows won't use the swap so won't be impacted; since Kali formatted it, it knows the new UUID so it won't be impacted; only others will be impacted (thus Ubuntu).  Use `blkid` to view your block devices ID's; then check what UUID's are listed in your file system table (/etc/fstab), eg. `grep UUID /etc/fstab` checking to see if the UUID= match what prior `blkid` showed.  I suspect your swap will contain a UUID that you don't have, this needs to be changed. (ie. edit /etc/fstab in the Ubuntu partition).  fyi: you need to elevate privileges to edit files in /etc.

Comment: @guiverc `blkid`
/dev/sda5: UUID="5dd061d5-d325-4bcc-83b2-fd1ed516e8cc" TYPE="swap",  
/dev/sda6: UUID="eadf1edf-19b3-4693-8551-6176e4bbed88" TYPE="ext4" 

, `grep UUID /etc/fstab`
UUID=eadf1edf-19b3-4693-8551-6176e4bbed88 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1, 
UUID=484A-BF6F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1, 
UUID=UUID=42a3362f-6945-43a2-8d36-ee195c856094 none            swap    sw              0       0

..............so i should change UUID=UUID=42a3362f-6945-43a2-8d36-ee195c856094 with UUID=5dd061d5-d325-4bcc-83b2-fd1ed516e8cc

Comment: @guiverc Thank you!! its working.

Comment: @guiverc you just have to write an answer ...

Comment: Swap partitions are passé  ever since Ubuntu 17.10, when swap files, which are easier to manage, became as fast as swap partitions. Swap partitions are needed only if you use hibernation. If you do not use hibernation, suggest you change to swap files after booting from a LiveUSB drive and using gparted http://gparted.org to delete the swap partitions and give their space to their adjacent Linux OSes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kali linux probably formatted the swap partition, and your Ubuntu is looking (and waiting) for the old swap UUID to appear, before eventually timeout occurs & it gives up (thus slower boot).

You need to change the UUID's for your old swap partition to match your new UUID.

As windows doesn't use a "linux" swap partition, it's boot-up speed will be normal, it was Kali that made the change so it's aware of it - thus why Ubuntu only is slower.

Use `blkid` to view your block devices ID's; then check what UUID's are listed in your file system table (/etc/fstab), eg. `grep UUID /etc/fstab` checking to see if the UUID= match what prior blkid showed.

I suspect your swap will contain a UUID that you don't have, this needs to be changed. (ie. edit `/etc/fstab` in the Ubuntu partition). fyi: you need to elevate privileges to edit files in /etc.

You provided in comments

```
/dev/sda5: UUID="5dd061d5-d325-4bcc-83b2-fd1ed516e8cc" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda6: UUID="eadf1edf-19b3-4693-8551-6176e4bbed88" TYPE="ext4" 

UUID=eadf1edf-19b3-4693-8551-6176e4bbed88 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=484A-BF6F /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
UUID=UUID=42a3362f-6945-43a2-8d36-ee195c856094 none swap sw 0 0
```

so you need to ensure "UUID=5dd061d5-d325-4bcc-83b2-fd1ed516e8cc" is in your Ubuntu `/etc/fstab`, ie. replace the "42a3362f-6945-43a2-8d36-ee195c856094" with "5dd061d5-d325-4bcc-83b2-fd1ed516e8cc"

*Note: there is an extra "UUID=" in there, I'm assuming is a typo, as it shouldn't be there, ie. UUID=UUID= is invalid.   Please edit your question in future and add additional information there, we can help format it in questions/answers*

Also please note:  *One benefit of a swap partition is it can be used by any GNU/Linux, ie. Kali can use one created by Ubuntu and vice-versa.  In fact nearly every Linux will use any swap partitions it finds which is why your 'Ubuntu' swap was re-formatted by Kali as it claimed 'ownership'.  The benefit of this (I'm a dual booter to of two Ubuntu's) is my one swap partition in my case can be used by my Ubuntu 18.04 & my 19.10 (for you it'll be Ubuntu & Kali sharing); reducing disk space needed for 'swap'.  If swapfiles were used, they wouldn't be sharing the space.  The only drawback is it'll mean you can't hibernate one to use the other, but I don't do that (and I bet you're current setup may not allow for that anyway)*